# Phantomjs with R

Tags: r, phantomjs, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from a web page. Since the page has a dynamic content, I used **phantomjs** to handle. But, with the codes I am using, I just can download the data seen on the web page. However, I need to input the date range and then submit to get all the data I want.

Here are the codes i used,

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

connection <- "pr.js"  

writeLines(sprintf("var page=require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
    page.open('%s',function(){
    console.log(page.content);//page source;
    fs.write('pr.html', page.content, 'w');
    phantom.exit();
    });",url),con=connection)

system_input <- paste(path,"phantomjs"," ",connection,sep="")

system(system_input)
```

Thanks to the codes, I have the html output of the webpage which has been created dynamically.

And as I stated, I also need a date input submit. But I couldn't achieve.

The url is : https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/piyasalar/gop/ptf.xhtml

Comment: I think you'll want to investigate seleniumPipes for this as you'll be able to do scripted data entry on form elements and even "click" on the "CSV download" icon to get pre-fab tables vs scrape the paged HTML. I took a look at using `POST` with populated form elements but b/c it uses java server faces with preserved view states so it's not doable w/o a full browser environment and you'll be able to script phantom or ffox/chrome with seleniumPipes better than trying to roll your own JS for it.

Comment: Thanks for the response @hrbrmstr . Selenium is a way to do that but it works slowly. Also it requires (if I am not mistaken) some special settings like admin log in, browser specification etc.Actually I do not want to mimic the entire page. I just want to make a post request, and retrieve the data either directly or clicking the download button programatically. I know it is easy to say but havent we got any other options?

Comment: Well, you can js-instrument phantom to click on the right things but you're replicating Selenium functionality by doing so, and you do need a full browser context to get to the resources (you know that already tho). Are you able to run Docker on your system? If so, https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr is a somewhat lighter weight option than selenium.

Comment: If you suggest that the thing I'm trying with the codes above will just be a replication of Selenium,that is  ok @hrbrmstr . I will not questionize, since you are an expert in this area. (I had a  chance to search you on web). Honestly, I don't even know what the Docker is. But I will have a look at. Nevertheless, I can not understand why it is so hard to make the same stuff what the browsers do. I guess the browsers handle big problems more than I think. Thank you very much.