# Automatically read contents of dynamic table written in javascript with R

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, automation, rvest

I am using data from an Indonesian website, which consists of a table that is dynamically generated (for different years and provinces) with (what seems to me) javascript. I try to automize this with R (using R Studio). The website is http://dibi.bnpb.go.id , and the table is on the subsite "Arrow --> Tabel" (I cannot provide a link to the page directly because it is dynamically generated)

I have searched for an api for the problem, but have not managed to. Even if I click through the page, the  links do not update. XPath, which I normally use for web-scraping, does not work.

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried using selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page does a POST request where the body params are based on your selections in the table. You will need to explore the params. I think it likely the params appear in the order of the dropdowns. Here is an example to retrieve 2018 data without the need for selenium. I used [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to monitor the web traffic when making selections manually.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

body <- list('vth' = 2018
             ,'vbl'=''
             ,'vtg'=''
             ,'vpr'=''
             ,'vkb'=''
             ,'vjn'=1)
r <- POST("http://bnpb.cloud/dibi/tabel1b",body = body)

t <- content(r) %>% html_node('#tbl') %>% html_table(fill = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Croote is correct, you will need to use a headless browser that will trigger all the necessary javascript code for you. You could try e.g. [RSelenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium) or perhaps use [phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014984/phantomjs-with-r).

Comment: Thank you, that helps! I am having several problems figuring out how to get this running and am only getting error messages. Is there a quick tutorial for non-computer-science people?

Comment: @JonathanOld have you looked at the [extensive documentation and vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html) of the RSelenium package?